# Problem with Python not opening up files in the correct order

Tags: python, button, kivy

I'm using Python 3.9 and Kivy

```
 from kivy.config import Config 
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'width',  800)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 600)
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import subprocess





presentation = Builder.load_file('UI_1.kv')

#Calling files to open 
#Always use popen 

class presentation(Widget):
    maths = ObjectProperty(None)
    physics = ObjectProperty(None)


    def btn_touch_up(maths):        
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        subprocess.Popen(['python',  'UI_MATH.py'])
        exit()



    def btn_touch_up(physics):        
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        subprocess.Popen(['python',  'UI_PHYSICS.py'])
        exit()




        

class MyApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return presentation()





Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

So that's the code I wrote. The problem is that when I run the app and click the first box (labeled maths), the code for the 2 box opens up (physics). When I clock the second box (Physics) it runs the correct code. Can someone point out my error so I can correct it? I'm fairly new so my code might seem like a mess...

Here is the code from the kivy (.kv) file:

```
<presentation>

    maths : maths
    physics : physics
    extra : extra


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb:0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos:8,498
            size:790,50
        
        Rectangle:
            pos:8,398
            size:790,50
        
        Rectangle:
            pos:8,298
            size:790,50

    GridLayout:

    

        cols:1
        size: root.width -10, root.height -550
        pos: 5, 500


        GridLayout:
            cols:1      
    

            Button:
                id: maths
                text:"1.Maths"
                on_press: root.btn_touch_up()
                



    
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width -10, root.height -550
        pos: 5, 400


        GridLayout:
            cols:1          

            Button:
                id: physics
                text:"2.Physics"
                on_press: root.btn_touch_up()



    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width -10, root.height -550
        pos: 5, 300


        GridLayout:
            cols:1


            

            Button:
                id: extra
                text:"3.Extra"
                on_press: root.btn_touch_up()
```

Thank you, and again, i'm really new and self taught so if there is something obviously wrong that I shouldn't do please point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for the `presentation` class has two definitions for the `btn_touch_up()` method. The result is that the second definition over-writes the first and the first definition can never be called (because it no longer exists). You just need to create unique method names, one for math and a different for physics.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of a unique method name, not really sure how to do it... Thanks!

Comment: You can use `btn_touch_up_math` for math and `btn_touch_up_physics` for physics.